# Map not displaying while working in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using sample code to display map based on locations in the sample database. That works fine.

[**Sample code Link**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Populate-Google-Maps-V3-with-Multiple-Markers-using-Address-Latitude-and-Longitude-values-stored-in-database.aspx)

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Database]

If I try to use this code in local and try to display the locations which are in my database, that doesn't work.

[image: Not open]

[image: Database]

Html Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
             {
                 "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                 "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                 "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                 "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
             }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
        ];
        window.onload = function () {
            LoadMap();
        }
        function LoadMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            var legend = document.getElementById("legend");
            legend.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title,
                    icon: data.icon
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:100px;height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

                legend.innerHTML += "<div style = 'margin:5px'><img align = 'middle' src = '" + marker.icon + "' />&nbsp;" + marker.title + "</div>";
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                var latitude = p.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = p.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("<%=hfLat.ClientID %>").value = latitude;
                document.getElementById("<%=hfLon.ClientID %>").value = longitude;
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "<div style = 'height:20px;width:100px'><b>You are here:</b>"
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            });
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        }

    </script>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="legend" style="display:none;">
            </td>
            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAV8AiebjdcoS-Ratewz-HDkFt7XCq3zOM&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLat" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLon" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label  Text="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label Text="Description" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PageLoad**

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData("select  * from FindLocation");
            rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**GetData**

```
private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Insert Query**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string latitude = hfLat.Value;
        string longitude = hfLon.Value;
        string Name = string.Empty;
        string Description = string.Empty;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("Insert into FindLocation(Name,Latitude,Longitude,Description)VALUES(@Name,@Latitude,@Longitude,@Description)"))
            {
                cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
                cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", latitude);
                cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", longitude);
                cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtdescription.Text);
                cmdd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Check for console errors.

Comment: first try to display the map in a plain html page.

Comment: No error sir @Majid

Comment: i tried but not working @sachin

Comment: then you should first start from there and fix that problem before looking into getting the markers right.

Comment: am sorry for that misunderstanding html is working fine @sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake Sir @Pranav Patel.Whenever I use '(apostrophe) in the description text box (Example: I'm), an error has occurred.Once I remove, everything works fine, so I guess '(apostrophe) shouldn't be used in the description.

[image: Working]

Comment: ok Ivin but not you have to escape those character in `"description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'` to make it fully work

Answer (score 1):

First of all you made a double call to the google API

(1) `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAV8AiebjdcoS-Ratewz-HDkFt7XCq3zOM&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>` 
(2) `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

so remove (2) from your code.

Second you mention in (1) url `&callback=initMap` so either change that to `LoadMap` or change `LoadMap` function name to `initMap`

Comment: @IvinRaj Pelase try once please and Two call to the same map API always gives conflict error on browser console.I have checked your code in my PC and found console error as confliction.

Comment: Okay sure sir I will @PranavPatel

Comment: Not working sir i think database issue @Pranav Patel

Comment: in this same code try to do same with static value like static markers value and check either value formatting issue or what?

Comment: I've found the mistake Sir @Pranav Patel.Whenever I use '(apostrophe) in the description text box (Example: I'm), an error has occurred.Once I remove, everything works fine, so I guess '(apostrophe) shouldn't be used in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionSteings[constr]. ConnectionString;
```